# Prevent orientation change when users pushes display-turn-off/on button

Tags: android

I've got an activity that is in a landscape mode - it's a player. Whenever I hit display-off button activity gets recreated and the screen goes black. After that I hit display-on to bring the interface back and the activity gets recreated again.

I guess this is because on my samsung i9001 display button not only shuts down the display but also brings that system-desktop to the foreground - so it's the first orientation change that causes activity recreation. Furthermore, when display gets active again and the activity starts it needs to change orientation/create activity again(not sure about it).

My question is how do I prevent the first recreation of the activity when I hit display-off. Is it possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by `display-off and display-on buttons`?

Comment: it's a button on the right side of the screen. standard one.

Comment: I've seen this before. The lock screen on a limited number of devices can cause landscape only activities to go portrait (or visa-versa) briefly. I don't think we ever found a way to stop it, and lived with the fact that it only happens on a few devices.

Comment: exactly, I'm using this feature - lock screen. Thanks, I'll keep on googling or abandon the feature.

Comment: I've just removed screen-lock mechanics but in vain.